# How can I move the character by touching the screen in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using this code and it works, but the problem is that if I touch anywhere on the screen, my character will teleport to the position I touch, instead of moving slowly to there, I'm building the game on Unity 2D and this is the code

```
 void Update () {

    if (Input.touchCount > 0) {

        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Vector3 touch_Pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
        transform.position = touch_Pos;
    }
}
```

Thanks You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html)

> Use the `MoveTowards` member to move an object at the `current` position toward the `target` position. By updating an object’s position each frame using the position calculated by this function, you can move it towards the `target` smoothly. Control the speed of movement with the `maxDistanceDelta` parameter. If the `current` position is already closer to the `target` than `maxDistanceDelta`, the value returned is equal to `target`; the new position does not overshoot `target`. To make sure that object speed is independent of frame rate, multiply the `maxDistanceDelta` value by `Time.deltaTime`.

```
// Set via the Inspector in Units/second
[SerializeField] private float _moveSpeed = 1;

// Could also already reference this in the Inspector if possible
[SerializeField] private Camera _camera;

private void Awake()
{
    // It is better to cache the camera reference since Camera.main is quite expensive
    if(!_camera) _camera = Camera.main;
}

private void Update () 
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0) 
    {
        var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        // Just so you know: Note that ScreenToWorldPoint takes a Vector3 where the 
        // Z component is the distance in front of the camera
        // currently you are passing in 0 so the object will move in the same plane
        // as the camera
        var touch_Pos = _camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, touch_Pos, _moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```